# awk preventing white spaces

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=source.txt
RES=res.txt

VAR1=match

rm -f $RES
sudo cat $FILE | while IFS= read LINE; do
    if [[ ! $(echo "$LINE" | grep $VAR1 ) ]]; then
        echo -e "$LINE" >> $RES
    else
                NEW_LINE=$(awk '{gsub("'"${VAR1}"'", ""); print}' <<< $LINE)
                echo -e "$NEW_LINE" | xargs >> $RES
    fi
done
```

source.txt:

```
rob     math
        science match something
  something match
hary    math linux
```

after executing the code, I would like to receive the following:

```
rob     math
        science something
  something
hary    math linux
```

But it removes the white spaces in the both affected lines. So I end up with the following result:

```
rob     math
science something
something
hary    math linux
```

Could you please help.

Comment: Your whole task looks like `sed 's/match//g'`..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your code can be summed up to this line in `Awk`, unless you are not sharing the whole requirement,

```
awk '{gsub("match","",$0)}1' source.txt
rob     math
        science  something
  something
hary
```

I would make the match configurable from a `bash` variable as

```
myVAR="match"
awk -v pat="${myVAR}" '{gsub(pat,"",$0)}1' source.txt
```

The `-v` flag allows you to *import* `bash` variables to the context of `Awk`. To complete your answer to write to a new file, I would do

```
awk -v pat="${myVAR}" '{gsub(pat,"",$0)}1' source.txt > res.txt
```

---

To answer your original attempt's  claim of eating up white-spaces, couple of points to be noted, the line

```
awk '{gsub("'"${VAR1}"'", ""); print}' <<< $LINE
```

is wrong if you want to preserve the spaces in each line you read, it should be double quoted as

```
awk '{gsub("'"${VAR1}"'", ""); print}' <<<"$LINE"
```

Even with that change, you have an `xargs` before writing to the file ( Not sure of the reason) but you have to know that *it swallows whitespaces* from the input stream. Removing it should solve your problem.

Just assuming you want to do such a trivial script for a such a simple use-case, the syntactically right approach (using your logic) would be,

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if grep -q "$VAR1" <<<"$line" ; then
        printf "%s\n" "$line" >> "$RES"
    else
        newLine=$(awk -v pat="${VAR1}" '{gsub(pat, "",$0); }1' <<<"$line")
        printf "%s\n" "$newLine" >> "$RES"
    fi
done <"$FILE"
```

Comment: Hi Inian, I removed the xargs and it preserves the white spaces. But if the word I want to remove is in the middle of the line, it replaces it with a space, which I don't want.

Comment: Which is not working from the script? may I ask? did you try my simple command, `awk -v pat="${myVAR}" '{gsub(pat,"",$0)}1' source.txt > res.txt`

Comment: @maimun4itu: did you refer my answer fully, did you double quote `$LINE` as `awk '{gsub("'"${VAR1}"'", ""); print}' <<< "$LINE"`

Comment: @maimun4itu: Refer my example of your script. Mark the answer accepted with an upvote, if it solved your problem

Comment: Hi, it is exactly as you say (my first comment was a mistake, I apologize for that). Your solutions work, and xargs swallows the white spaces. But without it I end up with additional space if the variable that should be removed is in the middle of the line.

Comment: @maimun4itu: Please try the script in my example and use it!

Comment: I tried the code several times, adding, removing spaces... the lines you provided above do the job, but the code keeps the res.txt file just the same as the source.txt :(

Comment: @maimun4itu: It is working perfectly fine for me with your example. You are either 1) running it incorrectly (or) 2) have a different file than the one I shared initially

Comment: I don't know what the reason is, but the fact is that you gave me examples that I can use in my code which will do the job. So thank you very much for your time and help.